# How to represent set of numbers defined by $b$ bits?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, computer-science, binary

I want a concise representation for the set of numbers defined by $b$ bits. For example, I want to write $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ except instead of $\mathbb{R}$ I want all number between $0$ and $2^b-1$ where $b$ is the number of bits.

I have no idea what tags to use for this question. Sorry.

Comment: There is no universally accepted way.  You could write $x \in BV(n)$, where $BV$ stands for "bit vectors."  Or perhaps be more explicit about your numbers being unsigned.  Pick something that works for you and, obviously, define it before you use it.

Comment: Why not just use $\{0,1\}^b = \{0,1\}\times\cdots\times \{0,1\}$, the Cartesian product of a 2-element set with itself $b$ times? The elements of this set correspond *exactly* with the set of numbers you mention.

Comment: @MPW You should convert your comment to an answer, as it is the right answer to the question.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin : Done! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Converted to answer from comment]*

Why not just use $\{0,1\}^b = \{0,1\}\times\cdots\times \{0,1\}$, the Cartesian product of a 2-element set with itself $b$ times? The elements of this set correspond exactly with the set of numbers you mention.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. Would this be called the b-ary Cartesian product?

Answer (score 0):

For the numbers $n$ with no more than $b$ bits, the valid values are $0 \leq n \leq 2^b-1$.

For the numbers $m$ with *exactly* $b$ bits (highest bit is $1$) then the values are $2^{b-1} \leq m \leq 2^b-1$.

The number of binary bits is independent of the base you express the number in, so defining it over the natural numbers is fine.